# Is that normal that nodes with same labels have different properties?

Tags: neo4j

In modeling, instances of the same label, i.e Student, have same set of properties. However, is it normal that instances of the same label have different sets of properties. For example, I have Product node:

```
(p:Product)-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(a:Attributes)
```

Different instances of Product result in different instances of Attributes. In this case, different Attributes nodes have very different properties.

Is this modeling normal? Different categories of products can have very different attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly allowed, as there is no table schema as in relational dbs to enforce homogenous properties.

While this provides great flexibility, it may introduce complexity. It's up to the modelers and administrators of the database to provide any guidelines or implement restrictions, if needed.

While that would usually be in the form of convention, APOC triggers (or kernel extensions if you want to implement this yourself) could be used to enforce only certain properties for a node of a given label.

Answer (score 1):

It's very useful to have different properties. For instance, I have a Y-DNA project with single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNP) Nodes. Some are on the know haplotree and some are not. So, I set a property InHGTree to Y or blank to reflect this. Now I can more readily create queries using the haplotree branching.

BTW, relationships can also have different properties with the same value. DNA results from an individual are in a "kit." The kit is related to numerous SNPs. You want to be able to determine whether the kit is positive or negative for the SNP. It is most logically to put this fact in the relationship between the kit and the SNP.